# Admin access on hive table in SQL Standard Based Hive Authorization

Tags: hive

I wanted to give admin access to role which must have all the access on hive table. e.g. alter, drop, insert, update, delete etc.
Along with ALL privileges we will get only

● INSERT privilege – gives ability to add data to an object (table).

● UPDATE privilege – gives ability to run update queries on an object (table).

● DELETE privilege – gives ability to delete data in an object (table).

Does anybody has ideas how could we dot that?

Comment: Do you mean you assigned all the rights via ranger, but when testing some actions fail? Please update the question to describe exactly what you do, what you expected to see, and what you see instead.

Comment: Im not using ranger, I am using hive sql based authorization for more details please refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+based+hive+authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-PrivilegesRequiredforHiveOperations . I have to give all (full access on hive table)

Comment: I now see I was thinking in the wrong direction, however the advice remains: please describe exactly what you do; what you expected to see; what you actually see

Comment: Creating/dropping tables requires database ownership: `ALTER (DATABASE|SCHEMA) database_name SET OWNER [USER|ROLE] user_or_role; `